# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python and no matching distribution when trying to install python 3.11?

Tags: python

I currently have python 3.12.2, and I'm trying to downgrade it to 3.11 so I can install tensorflow. When I type in `pip install python==3.11`, I get these two error messages:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python==3.11 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for python==3.11`

I tried using `python3 -m pip install python=3.11`, `pipwin install python==3.11`, and `python3 -m pip install --pre --upgrade python==3.11`, but neither worked.

My errors were `The system cannot execute the specified program.` and `'pipwin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: You can't install python using pip. Uninstall your Python 3.12 (using Add/Remove Programs) then install 3.11 from the setup executable.

Comment: You don't need to uninstall 3.12, you can install from the python downloads page directly, and then set the new 3.11 as the active python. See something like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip is the package installer for Python. [You can use pip to install packages from the Python Package Index and other indexes](https://pypi.org/project/pip/).

**Python is not a package and cannot be installed using pip.** You can have multiple installations of Python and use virtual environments to manage packages like tensorflow that requires specific python versions.

Keep your python 3.12, then install python 3.11 from the downloads page of the official python website. You can then create a python 3.11 [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and install your desired packages there.